# JAVA JPA unknown column entre entidades

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-jpa, annotation

Estou recebendo um erro que creio ser associado a relacionamento JPA. Tenho uma classe Usuario e uma classe Endereco. As relações são @OneToOne pra ambos, mas no momento de testá-las dá ruim.
Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT `TB_USUARIO`.`ID_USUARIO` AS `ID_USUARIO`, `TB_USUARIO`.`NR_CPF` AS `NR_CPF`, `TB_USUARIO`.`NM_USUARIO` AS `NM_USUARIO`, `TB_USUARIO`.`DS_LOGIN` AS `DS_LOGIN`, `TB_USUARIO`.`DS_EMAIL` AS `DS_EMAIL`, `TB_USUARIO`.`DS_SENHA` AS `DS_SENHA`, `TB_USUARIO`.`DS_UNIDADE` AS `DS_UNIDADE`, `TB_USUARIO`.`DT_CADASTRO` AS `DT_CADASTRO`, `TB_USUARIO`.`DT_ULTIMO_LOGIN` AS `DT_ULTIMO_LOGIN`, `endereco`.`DS_UF` AS `endereco_DS_UF`, `endereco`.`ID_ENDERECO` AS `endereco_ID_ENDERECO`, `endereco`.`DS_CEP` AS `endereco_DS_CEP`, `endereco`.`NR_IMOVEL` AS `endereco_NR_IMOVEL`, `endereco`.`DS_BAIRRO` AS `endereco_DS_BAIRRO`, `endereco`.`DS_MUNICIPIO` AS `endereco_DS_MUNICIPIO`, `endereco`.`DS_LOGRADOURO` AS `endereco_DS_LOGRADOURO`, `endereco`.`DS_COMPLEMENTO` AS `endereco_DS_COMPLEMENTO` FROM `TB_USUARIO` LEFT OUTER JOIN `TB_ENDERECO` `endereco` ON `endereco`.`usuario` = `TB_USUARIO`.`ID_USUARIO` WHERE `TB_USUARIO`.`DS_LOGIN` = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'endereco.usuario' in 'on clause'

Classe Usuario:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table("TB_USUARIO")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Usuario extends BaseEntity<Integer> {

    @Column("NM_USUARIO")
    private String nome;

    @Column("NR_CPF")
    private String cpf;

    @Column("DS_LOGIN")
    private String login;

    @Column("DS_SENHA")
    private String senha;

    @Column("DS_EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column("DT_ULTIMO_LOGIN")
    private Date dataUltimoLogin;

    @Column("DT_CADASTRO")
    private Date dataCadastro;

    @Column("DS_UNIDADE")
    private String unidade;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ENDERECO", referencedColumnName = "ID_ENDERECO")
    private Endereco endereco;

    @Override
    @Column("ID_USUARIO")
    public Integer getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

}
```

Classe Endereco:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table("TB_ENDERECO")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Endereco extends BaseEntity<Integer> {

    @Override
    @Column("ID_ENDERECO")
    public Integer getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @Column("DS_CEP")
    private String cep;

    @Column("DS_LOGRADOURO")
    private String logradouro;

    @Column("DS_COMPLEMENTO")
    private String complemento;

    @Column("DS_BAIRRO")
    private String bairro;

    @Column("NR_IMOVEL")
    private Integer numero;

    @Column("DS_MUNICIPIO")
    private String municipio;

    @Column("DS_UF")
    private String uf;

}
```

Acredito estar fazendo tudo certo, (só que não ne, senão estaria funcionando).

No banco, ambas tabelas estão criadas com os campos acima. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda pessoal.

Comment: Você não anotou ambas as classes com @Entity. Ou só esqueceu no post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O cerne do problema são as relações entre as entidades *Usuário* e *Endereço*. De acordo com o código fornecido, há apenas um relacionamento one-to-one unidirecional a partir da entidade *Usuário* para a entidade *Endereço*. Entranto, em sua pergunta, você diz *"as relações são one-to-one pra ambos"*. Então, qual é a real situação?

Assumindo que seja uma relação unidirecional da forma que está no código da pergunta, causa estranheza, ao ler o log de erro fornecido, uma referência a *Usuário* a partir de *Endereço*:

```sql
SELECT
// (...) colunas da query
FROM TB_USUARIO LEFT OUTER JOIN TB_ENDERECO endereco
ON endereco.usuario = TB_USUARIO.ID_USUARIO
WHERE TB_USUARIO.DS_LOGIN = ?
```

"ON **endereco.usuario** = TB_USUARIO.ID_USUARIO"

Ou seja, o provedor de persistência está esperando que exista um mapeamento na entidade *Endereço* da entidade *Usuário* - o que não existe. Você pode criar esse novo mapeamento com o seguinte trecho de código a ser inserido na classe `Endereco` :

```java
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "endereco") /* a entidade usuário continua sendo a dona do relacionamento */
    private Usuario usuario;
```

Apesar da pergunta não mostrar o teste que gera o erro do log apresentado, acredito que, seguindo essas considerações, você será capaz de resolver seu problema.

Answer (score -3):

As classes fornecidas estão corretas em termos de sintaxe e, portanto, não apresentam erros. No entanto, aqui estão algumas sugestões de melhoria para aprimorar o código:

1. Adicionar anotações @Id às propriedades que correspondem às chaves
   primárias das tabelas (geralmente chamadas "id" ou "codigo"), para
   indicar qual é a chave primária e permitir a geração do SQL
   apropriado.
2. Definir os tipos de dados corretos para cada coluna. Por
   exemplo, o número do imóvel deve ser do tipo String, e não Integer.
3. Adicionar validações de dados às propriedades relevantes usando
   anotações de validação, como @NotNull ou @Size, para garantir que os
   dados inseridos na tabela estejam corretos e evitar possíveis erros.

O erro pode estar ocorrendo também pelo fato que na cláusula JOIN do SQL gerado, há uma referência a uma coluna "endereco.usuario", que não existe na tabela TB_ENDERECO ou em qualquer uma das outras tabelas envolvidas na consulta. É possível ver que na classe Usuario, a anotação @JoinColumn especifica que a coluna de junção é "ID_ENDERECO", não "usuario".

Para corrigir o erro, é necessário alterar a anotação @JoinColumn na classe Usuario para especificar o nome correto da coluna de junção:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_ENDERECO", referencedColumnName = "ID_ENDERECO")
private Endereco endereco;
```